# Any implementations of XQueryX?

Tags: xquery

I'm looking for a way to convert XQuery expressions into [XQueryX](http://www.w3.org/TR/xqueryx/) (an XML syntax for XQuery).  Does anyone know of any implementation -- say in Python or Java?

Answer (score 5):

When I posed the [same question on vark.com](http://vark.com/t/4e7f7b), I got a reference to [XQ2XQX: XQuery to XQueryX](http://monet.nag.co.uk/xq2xml/#s3), a section on how to use a [stylesheet (xq2xqx.xsl)](http://monet.nag.co.uk/xq2xml/xq2xqx.xsl) to do the conversion.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.w3.org/2007/01/applets/xqueryApplet.html is an interactive applet-based page that allows you to translate arbitrary XQuery expressions to XQueryX. the parsing code has been generated from the XQuery grammar and is available as JavaCC/JJTree files from that page, which means that some building is required to turn that into an executable.