# HTML form to invoke XQuery files

Tags: forms, parameters, xquery, invoke, marklogic

We have quite a number of .xqy files in several folders.

Sometimes, I need to invoke an .xqy file (via Marklogic's CQ) to test if it's working.

But I find it rather cumbersome to have to know what parameters to pass in and specify them in the xquery in CQ.

Is there a tool out there that would generate an HTML form that presents to me the parameters of a given .XQY file and invokes it when I press a "submit" button ?

If there is none out there, would somebody here know of how to make such an HTML form ? Right now, I can't seem to find any readily-available xdmp or xquery commands to tell me if an .XQY file is invocable or what parameters it expects to be fed.

- Danny

Answer (score 1):

The XQuery standard doesn't support introspection, nor does MarkLogic provide any functions that help with that. The closest you can get with this is using the XQDoc documentation code that is capable of parsing the XQuery code itself and producing descriptions of all function signatures within modules.

You can find more details about it here: http://developer.marklogic.com/code/xqdoc-ws

It doesn't provide a 'Submit' button, but using the XML output of xqdoc, you could make that yourself..

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to convert your XQuery to XQueryX and you can then process this as XML using XQuery (or XSLT) to generate an XForm or XHTML Form.

Comment: @danny-sinang There are links mentioned in the following stackoverflow question if you are interested in this approach by Adam: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367823/any-implementations-of-xqueryx

Answer (score 0):

Since Danny mentioned unit testing, I'll risk plugging my own framework for that: https://github.com/mblakele/xqut

I usually run XQUT test suites in a cq buffer, but it would be easy enough to wrap one in a simple web page - with or without a form.