# XML syntax for XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm writing some higher-order XSLTs, and would like to operate with XPath expressions like they're XMLs, rather than with their string representations. Is there any research on this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath is a sublanguage of XQuery, and XQuery has an XML representation in the form of XQueryX, so you could use this.

Comment: [Just a link to simplify matters for anyone going this way.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367823/any-implementations-of-xqueryx)