# Coversion of XPath to XPath with namespaces

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I browsed through few of the documentations and links, but i didn't get any solution to convert the **XPath** for example say //h1[contains(@class,'product-title')] to //x:h1[contains(@class,'product-title')] where x being the **namespace** prefix.

I checked the documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/xpath.html but i didnt find anything useful there.

Please can somebody help me in providing some useful api which can be used for this purpose.

Thanks in advance
Ankit

Comment: What do you mean by convert ? Just prepend `x:` to existing xpath ?

Comment: I wouldnt say its just prepending x: because in my example Xpath was quite simple, but if its quite complex where we use all the XPath traversal techniques. I guess we cannot just assume putting x: before every //, can we?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manipulate and modify an XPath expression, you will need to parse it into a form that is amenable to such manipulation, and then convert it back into lexical XPath syntax. One way to do this is with XQueryX (because XPath is a subset of XQuery). See for example [Any implementations of XQueryX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367823/any-implementations-of-xqueryx)